# Fluent Assertions - Overriding comparison in ShouldBeEquivalentTo()

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have the following DTO:

```
public class Dto
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to override the comparison of a property using this syntax as per the [FA wiki](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#object-graph-comparison):

```
public void Override_test()
{
    // Arrange
    var actual = new Dto { Date = DateTime.Now };
    var expected = new Dto { Date = DateTime.Now };

    // Act

    // Assert
    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => 
        options.Using<DateTime>(x => x.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTime.Now)));
}
```

But the test does not compile.  I get this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyAssertionOptions<FluentAssertions.ShouldBeEquivalentTo.Override.Dto>.Restriction<System.DateTime>' to 'FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyAssertionOptions<FluentAssertions.ShouldBeEquivalentTo.Override.Dto>'
```

Can anyone advise the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to tell FA when to use that `Using` construction using the `WhenTypeIs<DateTime>()`. In other words:

```
actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expected, options => 
    options.Using<DateTime>(x => x.Subject.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTime.Now)).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>());
```

However, I would suggest not to rely on `DateTime.Now` too much. Instead, consider using something like Ayende Rahien has proposed in [this](http://ayende.com/blog/3408/dealing-with-time-in-tests) article.

Comment: Thanks Dennis - that worked.  Regarding abstracting away from `DateTime.Now` - I agree, I just haven't found a lightweight way I like yet.